# WPF DataGrid can't change selected row: stuck on first row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, .net-4.0, wpfdatagrid

In short, my problem is that the WPF DataGrid won't let me select anything other than the first row.  When I first fill it with data, no row is selected.  Next, no matter what row I click on, the first row lights up.  When I bind the SelectedItem property using OneWayToSource, I see that the *correct* row was indeed selected.  If I choose to click again on a different row, nothing happens: the UI remains stuck on the first row and the SelectedItem property retains the previously correct value.  At this point, I have to ctrl-click the *first* row to deselect things.  This allows me to repeat the above situation.

In other words:
- the UI seems to be out of sync with what is actually selected.
- Ctrl-click is required to de-select the selection.
- Ctrl-click must be executed on the first row even if the SelectedItem property indicates that a different row is selected.

I understand this is bizarre behavior.  I've tried to duplicate it in a separate project with no success.  As such, I'm just throwing this out there to see if anyone has any ideas why it might be acting this way?

The only things that I have not duplicated in my separate project is the use of MEF for the View/ViewModel hookup.  Everything else is the same.

EDIT:  I just replaced said DataGrid with a ListBox and am experiencing the same problem.  I'm using Snoop to try to figure out what might be applied to the control that would change its behavior so much.

Comment: Since this obviously is dependent on your specific code it would be helpful if you could provide said code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem was that the objects that I was adding to the DataGrid and ListBox had overridden Equals() and GetHashCode() functions.  These really screwed up the way both controls rendered which item was selected, therefore explaining the SelectedItem issue.  In the end, all the problems were solved by simply removing/fixing those overrides.

Woot!

Comment: Similar problem was found here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/64529f60-fe7b-4cf6-a686-3933e22e5169

Comment: And here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/8ddc921b-fecc-4053-b770-405bb7b070d6

Comment: Was it how you implemented Equals() and GetHashCode(). I would think this would only cause a problem if your implementation determined that all objects of that type are equal. Otherwise, that really shouldn't provide a problem if you're producing good hashes and comparing objects correctly.

Comment: The class had been modified by a coworker to reflect certain business rules.  The Equals() used a member enum variable to compare the classes in question, the GetHashCode() also relied on the GetHashCode method on the same member enum variable.  Apparently, the problem was fixed by moving the business rules elsewhere and deleting the overriden Equals() and GetHashCode().  While I do think that there were valid reasons for having that constraint in the model (and the code seemed correct), it seems to have been the root of my problems.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue with one of my datagrids and - as described above - I'd messed up my implementationof Equals() for the objects being bound to the grid. Problem now sorted.
It's not an obvious one, and caused some serious head scratching.

Comment: I was searching for an answer to this strange behaviour for months... This answer made my day happy!